# multiple top n queries

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm facing a hard time to get the following query:

Let's say I have a table with a lot of **teams** and each team has 15 **players** (one-to-many to a player table).

Those players are ordered within a team, through a Order column, from 0 to 14 and have two attributes:

- Points scored (integer)
- wasSick (boolean, or integer with values 0 for false or 1 for true)

I'd like a query that returns a **row for each team**, where the first column is the team ID (primary key) and the second column is the sum of the points scored from the first 11 players of each team that were not sick using the order defined by the Order column.

If more than 3 players were sick for a team, it would use all remaining ones.

This is against an **Oracle** database. I tried using ROWNUM but I need a similar rownum that resets for each aggregation. The query may contain subqueries or use the WITH clause.

Thanks!

*PD: If you guessed, they are football/soccer teams.*

**EDIT**

The attribute used to know the order of the players in a team is the order column. Let's call it Position column, and it has integer from 0 to 14. So if in a team, players 2 and 4 are sick, I'd need the sum of the points made by players 0,1,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 and 12.

My attempt was something like:

```
SELECT t.id, sum(p.points) FROM team t, points p WHERE p.t_id = t.id AND p.wasSick = 0 AND ROWNUM < 12 GROUP BY p.t_id
```

What's wrong here is that I'm missing ORDER BY p.position and that ROWNUM doesn't reset between teams.

Comment: When you say "points scored from the first 11 players of each team" is there any attribute/column that can be used to order them?

Comment: can you post your attempt(s)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is no reference to a field that can be used to identify the first 11 players (if none of the players in the team are sick) I used rowid to order them. If you can update the question with such a field I can change the query. Till then :

```
SELECT team_id,
       SUM(points)
  FROM (
        SELECT t.team_id, 
               p.points
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY team_id ORDER BY player_id, p.rowid) rn
          FROM teams t, players p
              WHERE t.team_id = p.team_id
                AND p.wasSick = 0
        )
 WHERE rn < 12
 GROUP BY team_id
```

Comment: I found ROW_NUMBER while searching for a solution but didn't understand it. It's clearer now with your example. I'll try this approach when I get back to work tomorrow.

Comment: Yes, row_number was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
select teamid, 
       sum(pointscored)
  from (select teamid, 
               pointscored, 
               row_number() over (partition by teamid order by orderid) rn
          from (select 1 teamid, 1 playerid, 0 orderid, 1 pointscored, 0 wassick from dual union all
                select 1 teamid, 2 playerid, 1 orderid, 1 pointscored, 0 wassick from dual union all
                select 1 teamid, 3 playerid, 2 orderid, 1 pointscored, 0 wassick from dual union all
                select 1 teamid, 4 playerid, 3 orderid, 1 pointscored, 0 wassick from dual union all
                select 1 teamid, 5 playerid, 4 orderid, 1 pointscored, 0 wassick from dual union all
                select 1 teamid, 6 playerid, 5 orderid, 1 pointscored, 0 wassick from dual union all
                select 1 teamid, 7 playerid, 6 orderid, 1 pointscored, 0 wassick from dual union all
                select 1 teamid, 8 playerid, 7 orderid, 1 pointscored, 0 wassick from dual union all
                select 1 teamid, 9 playerid, 8 orderid, 1 pointscored, 0 wassick from dual union all
                select 1 teamid, 10 playerid, 9 orderid, 1 pointscored, 0 wassick from dual union all
                select 1 teamid, 11 playerid, 10 orderid, 1 pointscored, 0 wassick from dual union all
                select 1 teamid, 12 playerid, 11 orderid, 1 pointscored, 0 wassick from dual union all
                select 1 teamid, 13 playerid, 12 orderid, 1 pointscored, 0 wassick from dual union all
                select 1 teamid, 14 playerid, 13 orderid, 1 pointscored, 0 wassick from dual union all
                select 1 teamid, 15 playerid, 14 orderid, 1 pointscored, 0 wassick from dual union all
                select 2 teamid, 1 playerid, 0 orderid, 1 pointscored, 1 wassick from dual union all
                select 2 teamid, 2 playerid, 1 orderid, 1 pointscored, 1 wassick from dual union all
                select 2 teamid, 3 playerid, 2 orderid, 1 pointscored, 1 wassick from dual union all
                select 2 teamid, 4 playerid, 3 orderid, 1 pointscored, 1 wassick from dual union all
                select 2 teamid, 5 playerid, 4 orderid, 1 pointscored, 0 wassick from dual union all
                select 2 teamid, 6 playerid, 5 orderid, 1 pointscored, 0 wassick from dual union all
                select 2 teamid, 7 playerid, 6 orderid, 1 pointscored, 0 wassick from dual union all
                select 2 teamid, 8 playerid, 7 orderid, 1 pointscored, 0 wassick from dual union all
                select 2 teamid, 9 playerid, 8 orderid, 1 pointscored, 0 wassick from dual union all
                select 2 teamid, 10 playerid, 9 orderid, 1 pointscored, 0 wassick from dual union all
                select 2 teamid, 11 playerid, 10 orderid, 1 pointscored, 0 wassick from dual union all
                select 2 teamid, 12 playerid, 11 orderid, 1 pointscored, 0 wassick from dual union all
                select 2 teamid, 13 playerid, 12 orderid, 1 pointscored, 0 wassick from dual union all
                select 2 teamid, 14 playerid, 13 orderid, 1 pointscored, 0 wassick from dual union all
                select 2 teamid, 15 playerid, 14 orderid, 1 pointscored, 0 wassick from dual
               ) teams
         where wassick = 0
       )
 where rn <= 11
group by teamid;
```

which returns:

```
    TEAMID SUM(POINTSCORED)
---------- ----------------
         1               11
         2               11

2 rows selected.
```

Comment: pretty much the same as @Cybernate but order by orderid in the windowing clause.  Great minds think alike.

Comment: Good, you understood what my problem is, now I have to understand your solution! A query within a query within a query sounds deep, not to mention that the query I need will already go inside a larger query.

Comment: @Luciano:  Nested queries are not to be feared.  Most of my query is sample data.  What it is doing is: 1) Excluding sick people 2) Using an analytic function (row_number) for each team to give an ascending number to each row for that team ordered by orderid 3) Kicking out all but the numbers 1-11 from the results of our analytic function 4) Grouping by team to sum up the points.